# iOS - NSJSONSerialization throwing some really weird errors

Tags: ios, json

Ok so I am fetching a JSON file with the following code

```
- (void)dataRequest {
    NSURL *dataURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"link to JSON file"];
    NSURLRequest *dataRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:dataURL];
    NSURLConnection *dataConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:dataRequest delegate:self];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    NSError *dataError;

    _dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&dataError];

    if (_dataDictionary == nil) {
        NSLog(@"JSON error: %@", dataError);
    }
}
```

Xcode seems to randomly want to parse the data correctly, but sometimes it instead throws these seemingly random errors (the first two often shows up in the log together):

> 2015-05-25 18:09:35.506 UserProject[703:13236] JSON error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Unexpected end of file while parsing object.) UserInfo=0x7fb5735775b0 {NSDebugDescription=Unexpected end of file while parsing object.}
>
> 2015-05-25 18:09:35.510 UserProject[703:13236] JSON error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0x7fb57357d3b0 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}
>
> 2015-05-25 18:12:56.577 UserProject[835:15617] JSON error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Unescaped control character around character **insert recurring but seemingly random number here**.) UserInfo=0x7fbb71e67e10 {NSDebugDescription=Unescaped control character around character **insert recurring but seemingly random number here**.}

I also have a problem where it parses successfully, however if I change this line in my JSON

```
"Title": "Projet Cars”,
```

To

```
"Title": "Projet CARS”,
```

Then Xcode throws this error:

> 2015-05-25 18:12:56.577 UserProject[835:15617] JSON error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Unescaped control character around character 67.) UserInfo=0x7fbb71e67e10 {NSDebugDescription=Unescaped control character around character 67.}

Character 67 being two spaces after "Title": "Projet CARS”

```
"Title": "Projet CARS”  < character 67 here
```

Changing the line back to "Title": "Projet Cars” doesn't remove the error, however the error remains until I remove the "Title": "Projet Cars” and the other entries in the object entirely, and then waiting some time before I put it back in to have it working again. When I try to change "Title": "Projet Cars” to "Title": "Projet CARS” after I pasted it in (from another file I have) after waiting some time , it breaks again with said error.

This error have also happened multiple times without changing anything at all, simply rerunning the application in the simulator have been enough for Xcode to complain about a seemingly random character. For example it might work completely fine, then when rerunning the app it says there is something wrong at 1547, and then when rerunning the app after that it says it is character 5769 that's causing issues, and then it will consistently say its character 5769 where the error is at from here on. The problem is that it's always just in blank space or in the middle of a text with normal characters such as letters and numbers, nothing that should cause issues.

My JSON is built up like this:

```
{
"Array of objects": [
      {
      "Title": "entry 1",
      "Description": "entry 2",
      "Date": "entry 3",
      "DateText": "entry 4",
      "Picture": "entry 5",
      "Author": "entry 6",
      "Genre": "entry 7",
      "Features": "entry 8",
      "AltPicture": "entry 9",
      "Extra": "entry 10",
      "Sources": "entry 11",
      "Video": "entry 12"
      },
      {
      "Title": "entry 1",
      "Description": "entry 2",
      "Date": "entry 3",
      "DateText": "entry 4",
      "Picture": "entry 5",
      "Author": "entry 6",
      "Genre": "entry 7",
      "Features": "entry 8",
      "AltPicture": "entry 9",
      "Extra": "entry 10",
      "Sources": "entry 11",
      "Video": "entry 12"
      }

      // And so on..
      ]
}
```

I save my JSON using UTF-8, and it's hosted using the public folder in DropBox.

I thought it was perhaps because of a byte order mark, however I use TextEdit and by default it doesn't save the files with BOM's.

Does anybody know what's going on exactly?..

**EDIT**: Ok so there are two problems here as stated in the answers, the first is to use a proper text editor meant for programming, the other is to fix my code that does the actual downloading (first code sample in my post). 
- Thanks for all your answers, I'll take a look at your answers and fix my code.

Comment: didreceiveData doesn't have your all data. It will keep on calling this method untill you receive all of your data and                                            calls                                                             - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection. You need to put NSJsonSerialization in this method. Following this tutorial on how to append your data in didreceiveData   http://codewithchris.com/tutorial-how-to-use-ios-nsurlconnection-by-example/

Comment: Wasn't seen that. When i was posting there was no answer so it can go vice-versa.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! It seems that it's TextEdit that's causing the issues (as seen in the answer by Droppy), using a text editor meant for programming should be the answer.

EDIT: Someone suggested that TextEdit was a bad text editor for programming, it seems his/her answer is deleted.

Comment: Using a better text editor will fix that one little issue. You still have code that needs to be fixed as stated in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with how you get the data. You are not implementing the proper delegate methods. The key to know is that the `didReceiveData:` delegate method can be called several times. You need to append all of the received data together and process it only when you have it all (at least in this case).

Start by adding an instance variable to your class:

```
NSMutableData *_receivedData;
```

Now update your `NSURLConnection` delegate methods like this:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    _receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [_receivedData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSError *dataError;

    _dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_receivedData options:kNilOptions error:&dataError];

    if (_dataDictionary == nil) {
        NSLog(@"JSON error: %@", dataError);
    }
}
```

Of course you also need to make sure you use proper quote characters in your JSON file.

Comment: Just to make it noob friendly, [_receivedData appendData data]; should be [_receivedData appendData:data]; with a colon added between appenData and data

Comment: @Chikara Thanks. Fixed. Next time, feel free to fix such a typo.

Comment: Wow didn't realize you could do that, but yea I can see the edit button under your answer now that you mention it, will remember that.

Answer (score 4):

This is not legal JSON syntax:

```
"Title": "Projet Cars”
                     ^
```

it should be:

```
"Title": "Projet Cars"
```

Comment: To be clear, the problem is that the text editor replaced `"` with `U+201D RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK`, but that's only one of the problems in the question.

Comment: To add to what @BrianNickel said: if you insist on using TextEdit for anything programming related, go to TextEdit->Preferences and set the structure to 'flat text'. If it's set to something different it will add extra stuff or could use a different kind of quotation marks. This can cause problems with parsing JSON or mess up podfiles for example.